# TFS Warehouse field OriginalEstimate

Tags: tfs, tfs-warehouse

One of our customer is using scrum based project and he is looking for the original estimate field in the warehouse table. As we know it's available for Agile based project but not for the scrum one's, is there any possible way to get the customized field added and get that populated in warehouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in Scrum there is a equivalent “**Effort**” field on the Product Backlog Item is meant to be any unit the team decides they want to use. See this [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2346623-update-how-effort-estimates-work-in-the-scrum-tfs) for details.

> A project created with the Agile or CMMI process template will have
>   that field and it will create the field in the cube. Scrum projects
>   don't have that field, so if your project is created with the Scrum
>   process template your Task work item does not have that field and the
>   value in the cube will be blank.
>
> You can customize your Task work item to add the field.

So, yes, you can customize your Task work item to add the field if you want to capture the `original estimate` of the task. You can use the process editor in the [power tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2013Power) for that purpose or you can use `witadmin`. See [Add or modify a field to track work](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-field?view=vsts) for details.

You can reference below screenshot to add the `original estimate` filed for Task with the `Process Editor`:

[image]